# Android Emulator and Google Play Store displaying message app not compatible

Tags: android-emulator, google-play

Android Emulator displays message “Your device isn't compatible with this version” when using Google Play Store. 
It works well with real devices (or at least with the devices I have tested).
These are my Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />  <!-- in-app products -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />   <!-- For setMasterSyncAutomatically -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/> 

<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add this:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
```

Because Android emulators don't have bluetooth.